# The determinant of identity matrix plus the sum of outer products of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $I\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be the identity matrix. Let $x_{1},x_{2}\ldots,x_{N}$
and $y_{1},y_{2}\ldots,y_{N}$ be vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{d\times1}$.

Is there some expression for

$\mathrm{det}\left(I+x_{1}y_{1}^{\top}+\ldots+x_{N}y_{N}^{\top}\right)?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Sylvester's determinant identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity) (also called the Weinstein-Aronszajn identity) allows you to rewrite this in a way that is particularly useful when $N < d$. Let $X$ denote the matrix whose columns are $x_1,\dots,x_N$ and $Y$ the matrix whose columns are $y_1,\dots,y_N$. Then the determinant you're after is $\det(I + XY^T)$, and we have
$$
\det(I_d + XY^T) = \det(I_N + Y^TX).
$$
In terms of the original vectors, this can be written as
$$
\det(I_d + x_1y_1^\top + \cdots + x_Ny_N^\top) = \det \left[I_N + \pmatrix{y_1^\top x_1 & \cdots & y_1^\top x_N\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
y_N^\top x_1 & \cdots & y_N^\top x_N} \right].
$$
Of course, this determinant can be written out as a polynomial over the dot-products $y_i^\top x_j$ if that is desired, but I'd say that this is impractical for $N > 3$.

Comment: Thank you, but I think that an expression that includes the vectors is better.

Comment: @Joshua See my latest edit. Perhaps this rewritten version is satisfactory.